# background not showing up (file path double checked)

Tags: html, css, background

just a short question, I started making a website locally (no server involved at this moment) and right now I'm trying to add a background image. The background is in the following path: `[root]/img/binarybg.jpg`

My css file is in `[root]/css/main.css`

So my css looks like this:

```
body {
background-image:src("../img/binarybg.jpg");
}
```

I have no idea why it's not showing up, could it be because the website is stored locally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You used `src(path)`, it should be `url(path)`.

Having the file stored locally is not a problem to load images from CSS as long as the paths can be resolved correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it wrong. Do it like this instead:

```
background: url("file://PATH_HERE\binarybg.jpg")
```

Example:

```
background: url("file://C:\YShakker\img\binarybg.jpg")
```